# Overwriting bytes of a binary file from an offset in C++

Tags: c++, file-io

In this operation I copy my source binary file first.

Then I wish to start overwriting bytes in the copied file starting from a specific offset.

I move with `seekp(offset,std::ios::beg)` to the desired position and I start the overwriting process with

`file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&my_vector[0]),  my_vector.size()*sizeof(unsigned char));`

Then close the file.

When I open processed file in hex editor all the bytes I see before the offset I have started writing are **zeros** and the bytes I have written with this operation are sucesfully written.

The mode of the stream is `std::fstream(path, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);`

Is there something I am missing in this operation?

[image]

Comment: [C++ overwriting data in a file at a particular position](//stackoverflow.com/a/7300338)

Comment: By the way before asking I searched 4-5 times for a similar question but didn't seem to find this one thank you.

Comment: It's not an _exact_ duplicate, but has the info you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to preserve the old contents, open it in in/out mode. i.e. `ios::in | ios::out`.

Additionally, if you're using `std::fstream` this is the default behavior, so you could have just used: `std::fstream(path, std::ios::binary)`.